# Navigating from React to a non React web page on the same domain

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redirect

**Edit**

I have found that if I navigate directly to the page outside of React, I can view the correct page. But, once I enter the React application, I can not navigate out of it.

Things I have tried,

1. `window.locastion` I tried a few variations of window.location.

Example -

```
 <a class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" onClick={() => window.location.replace('https://www.example.com/help.html')}>
    Get Started Now!
    </a>
```

2. .htaccess

`redirect newfile.php https://example.com/newfile.php`

3. a href

`<a href="https://example.com/newfile.php">Click</a>`

**Background**

I am integrating a React application into an existing PHP site. There are 4 modules in the website and I want to replace the public module with the React application. I have created `<a href>` tags to link to the same domain but outside of React web pages of the other 3 modules in the application.

**Problem**

After uploading the React application, when I click the `<a>` tags rarely do they open the correct page. Most of the time the `<a>` tag links to the correct URL path but the application stays inside of the React application and will not leave to go to the outside of React but inside the same domain web page.

**Example**

*Main Website URL*
https://www.example.com/ // React Application
*a href tag clicked*
https://www.example.com/other/webpage // Should be the PHP site

The second scenario in the example above almost always shows a React application without any content. Just the header and footer.

I have multiple links through the website and they are all behaving the same way.

**Code Example**

This should load a PHP web page outside of React but instead it loads the React application,

```
    <li role="presentation" class="">
       <a href="https://www.example.com/some/page" role="button">
         Login / Register
      </a>
   </li>
```

**Question**

What is the correct way to ensure I my users will see the correct pages when they click the `<a href>` tags?

Answer (score 0):

May be you try with use react-router-dom and instead a href= /a try use Link to=  /Link

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else dealing with this issue, the problem was a caching issue once the Rect application had been loaded. The direct problem and solution was the

```
registerServiceWorker();
```

In order to solve this and get the links to work again I just had to comment out the register service worker.

```
// registerServiceWorker();
```

I have not discovered why this causes this behavior but it fixes the issue for the time being. I am not sure how comfortable I am with this and I wonder if it is a bug. I am quite surprised this has not come up in the past since there is not any information on this.